# Sort order in `Dir.entries`

Tags: ruby

Is there a fixed/default sort order in which `Dir.entries` returns results? I know by experience that the first two entries are `"."` and `".."`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to the Ruby language docs, [`Dir.entries()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html#M000607) does not guarantee any particular order of the listed files, so if you require some order it's best to do it explicitly yourself.

For example, if you need to sort by file modification time (oldest to newest), you could do the following:

```
Dir.entries('.').sort_by { |x| File.mtime(x) }
```

Comment: Or `.sort_by { |a| File.stat(a).mtime }` to skip a few `stat` calls.

Comment: Or `.sort_by { |a| File.mtime(a) }` to skip a few `File::Stat` allocations.

Comment: Note that since ruby 3.0, results from the following methods are sorted by default:

`Dir.glob('./lib/**/*.rb')` or alternatively `Dir['./lib/**/*.rb']`

See: https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Dir.html#method-c-entries; https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Lint/RedundantDirGlobSort

Answer (score 13):

I think there is no default sort order, but you can use `Dir.entries('some_path_to_dir').sort` to sort them in ASC way.

Comment: Hi.. thanks. The reason for my asking is that there is already some code (in a system at my work place) which assumes that Dir.entries() will return data in a specific order (ascending-last-modified-date). So, I was not sure if I should stick to it or change it to be sure of the order.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on  @maerics' answer ,the below  ignores `. && ..` ,  regex based filter , and select the latest file if desired.

```
    Dir.chdir(in_dir)
    target_file   =  Dir.entries(in_dir).select(|x| 
                     x != '.' && 
                     x != '..' && 
                     x =~ /\somefile.txt\z/).sort_by{|f|File.mtime(f)}.last(1)
   puts "here i am #{target_file}"
```