# How to split routes.rb into smaller files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to split Rails 3.X routes.rb file?

We have so many resources it is difficult to find them. I would like to split at least APP and REST API routes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do that:

routes.rb

```
require 'application_routes'
require 'rest_api_routes'
```

lib/application_routes.rb

```
YourApplication::Application.routes.draw do
  # Application related routes
end
```

lib/rest_api_routes.rb

```
YourApplication::Application.routes.draw do
  # REST API related routes
end
```

**UPDATE: (This method has since been removed from Rails)**

Rails edge just got a great addition, multiple route files:

```
# config/routes.rb
draw :admin

# config/routes/admin.rb
namespace :admin do
  resources :posts
end
```

This will come handy for breaking down complex route files in large apps.

Comment: This is only working in development for me, once I start caching the classes it doesn't work anymore

Comment: The multiple route file support was removed: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/5e7d6bba79393de0279917f93b82f3b7b176f4b5

Answer (score 7):

In Rails3, you can set the configs in config/application.rb

```
config.paths.config.routes.concat Dir[Rails.root.join("config/routes/*.rb")]
```

Comment: this worked better for me rather than requiring the files in routes.rb

Comment: What's the order of the routes with this approach?

Comment: @Robin I experimented in our app on my OS X dev machine. I put numbers in front of the filename and the routes in "1_routes.rb" came before "2_routes.rb", but after when I changed the "1" to a "3". But it [seems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389733/sort-order-in-rubys-dir-entries-method) the order of `Dir.entries` is not guaranteed, so you probably need `Dir[…].sort` to rely on this.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `config.paths["config/routes"]`? Your code raises undefined method error.

Answer (score 3):

Rails 3.2.11

`config.paths["config/routes"].concat Dir[Rails.root.join("config/routes/*.rb")]`