# How do I organize files by creation date?

Tags: ruby, unix, file-organization

How would I sort a directory into files created before and after any given time and date?

I need to make two lists, one of files before, and the other of files after, a certain date/time.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389733/sort-order-in-rubys-dir-entries-method

Comment: How do you know when the file was created?  The traditional UNIX filesystem does not know.  (`ctime`/`st_ctime` does not record a file's creation time.)

Comment: +1 @pilcrow. `ctime` can't be relied on because it means two different things depending on the OS and the version of Ruby. Use `mtime` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The creation time with Ruby on OS X is not available through the [File](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html) API. One way is shelling out to `stat(1)`. Not pretty but does at least return the creation (a.k.a birth) time:

```
def birth(file)
  Time.at(`stat -f%B "#{file}"`.chomp.to_i)
end

Dir.entries('.').sort_by {|f| birth f }
```

Or use the partition answer given.

Here's a detailed post on a common misconception: [ctime does *not* mean creation time](http://userprimary.net/posts/2007/11/18/ctime-in-unix-means-last-change-time-not-create-time/).

Comment: Thanks! You would also want to escape the #{file} with apostrophes quotation marks so that you won't have troubles with filenames that have spaces. :)

Comment: According to http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-birthtime creation time should be available through the File API, but this does not always seem to work. It works in my OSX, but not on my Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 2):

`Dir["dir_path/*"].sort_by { |p| File::Stat.new(p).birthtime }` works on macos

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Enumerable#partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition):

```
files = Dir.entries('.')
time = Time.parse("2013-09-01")
before, after = files.partition { |file| File.ctime(file) < time }
```

As the Tin Man noted, `ctime` is not the only file time method. Maybe `atime` or `mtime` is a better choice.

Comment: `ctime` is not the creation time. "
Returns the change time for stat (that is, the time directory information about the file was changed, not the file itself)." Neither Linux or Mac OS keep file creation time, only Windows does, so most languages don't attempt to report it. The value returned would be different across OSes resulting in confusion. `mtime` is a better choice.

Comment: @theTinMan I've added a note to my answer. BTW, OS X keeps the file creation time (at least on HSF volumes), but it's not available as a Ruby method.

Comment: It keeps it as a side-car file as part of the Finder's information in an extended attributes file. Standard *nix OS calls can't reach it, which is why Ruby can't get it. Ruby prior to 2.0 was consistent in this. Why they changed to an inconsistent model is beyond me but I think it was a poor decision.

Comment: It's not POSIX, but BSD's `stat(2)` returns a birth time.

Answer (score 0):

> ctime
>
> Returns the change time for stat (that is, the time directory
>   information about the file was changed, not the file itself).
>
> Note that on Windows (NTFS), returns creation time (birth time).
>
> http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File/Stat.html#method-i-ctime

so you can do something like this.

```
Dir.entries('.').sort {|a,b| File.stat(a).ctime <=> File.stat(b).ctime}
```

Comment: There is also mtime, that returns modification time rather than creation time

Comment: Suggest [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) rather than `sort`, for efficiency.

Comment: It's important to emphasize you can't count on file creation information being available. Only Windows captures it, so the results would be different if the code was run on non-Windows systems. As a result you should use `mtime` because it's a more usable value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer. You can sort the files in a directory by their modified time with something along these lines using `File.new('filename').mtime`

```
files_hash = Hash.new

Dir.foreach('.') do |file_name|
  modified_time = File.new(file_name).mtime
  unless file_name == '.' || file_name == '..' then
    files_hash[file_name] = modified_time
  end
end

# Sort the hash.
files_hash = files_hash.sort_by {|key, value| value}

files_hash.each do |name, time|
  puts "#{name} was modified at #{time}"
end
```