# Ruby: Pull the last downloaded file of specific file type and print file name console

Tags: ruby, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber

I'm trying to run an automation test and have it download a document and print its file name into the console. I'm having trouble helping it locate the most recent document. I'm using ruby and cucumber with Firefox. Below is my specific step-def language that works to pull a file, but not exactly the most recent file:

```
When(/^I can see the file name of download pdf from the (.+) directory displayed on the console 
screen$/) { |path| 
 Dir.foreach(path) do |fname|
if fname.include?(".pdf")
  @file_name = fname
  break
end
```

`end

puts @file_name
 }`

I tried to follow the post's advice. I'm not getting an document displayed now at all. Previously I would get the initial downloaded document (and no subsequent ones). Code -

```rb
When(/^I can see the file name of download pdf from the (.+) directory displayed on the console screen$/) { |path|
  Dir.glob(path).max_by do |fname| File.mtime(fname)
    #Dir.foreach(path) do |fname|
     if fname.include?(".pdf")
      @file_name = fname
      break
    end
  end
  puts @file_name
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort order in \`Dir.entries\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389733/sort-order-in-dir-entries)

Comment: You may want to use `end_with?('.pdf')` instead as a file called `hacker.pdf.exe` will be misconstrued by this as a PDF.

Comment: I wasn't able to get that to work perfectly, so I added a line before the download.. ````When /^I clean out all PDF before download a new pdf$/ do
  FileUtils.rm_rf(Dir.glob('C:/downloads/*.{pdf,PDF}'))
end````

Answer (score 1):

```rb
Dir.glob("*.pdf").max_by { |f| File.mtime(f) }
```

<sup>Credit goes to: [Ruby: Finding most recently modified file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823507/ruby-finding-most-recently-modified-file)</sup>

[image]

Comment: I made an edit to my post. Had issues with the comment.

Comment: You don't need to filter for the .pdf inside a block. Block should return only the mtime, which then goes to the "max_by", so you get the filename of the most recent file. This one-liner is everything you need.

Comment: Added the screenshot to the answer so you can see the result.